# How do I change geolocation of photos in the Photo app?

Tags: iphone, photos, photos.app, geolocation

The thing is, there is a bunch of photos I've taken that are referred at the wrong location.

For example: there is a picture of my dad that was taken at my home in Barueri, Brazil and the Photo app says that it was taken at Ar Riyad, Saudi Arabia

Lots of other photos are located in places like Africa and Western Asia, places that I've never been before.

Is there a way to correct it?

Comment: Wow, that is seriously off! They were taken on your iPhone? Are you sure there isn't a root problem to deal with future images?

Comment: Which version of Mac OS are you on? Location capabilities in Photos have changed with El Capitan, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know a way to edit the location of photos on the iPhone but with El Capitan you can now edit them in the Desktop Photo App:

1. select the one or more photos
2. press <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> or use Window -> Info
3. check/enter and/or edit the location information under Location

Comment: This works for photos that don't have a location. Right now, for me, for photos that do have a location, the 'location' field shows the text "Looking up location info", keeps showing that text, and I can not click into that field to change it.

Answer (score 1):

That information is based on the GPS information in the [EXIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) metadata, and cannot be changed in the Photos app.

If you export the photo to your Desktop, then open it in **Preview**, you should be able to <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> and select the 'More Info' tab (the 'i' with a circle around it) and check the 'GPS' tab to see if the information is correct. If you want to change the GPS coordinates, there are a number of third-party tools to do this – but I generally use [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Third party apps like EXIF Viewer by Fluntro to bulk edit location of multiple photos together.

Analysing,
Barueri, Brazil coordinates - `23.5113° S, 46.8729° W`
Ar Riyad, Saudi Arabia coordinates - `24.7136° N, 46.6753° E`

Root cause of the problem might be,
The Camera app which writes GPS data might have incorrectly stored "N" instead of "S" and "E" instead of "W". This doesn't happen with iOS's default camera app. So you might be using third party Camera app i guess.

Disclaimer: I have developed the EXIF Viewer by Fluntro App :)

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/exif-viewer-by-fluntro/id944118456?mt=8
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ycz0b0uDn9A

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you already solved

Koredoko is what you are searching for

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/koredoko-exif-and-gps-viewer/id286765236?mt=8

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the link you provided will answer the question.  It's preferable to not just post links.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review