# Editing/correcting "Places" in macOS Photos

Tags: macos, photos, big-sur, photos.app

I have about 300 images taken here at "Home" as labeled in macOS Photos (v 6.0, Big Sur) but when I look at "Places" they are scattered all over the place. I have 1 photo stack with 20 photos that seems to be in the front yard, another 25 out in the back yard, 17 that are slightly down the street but I know were taken inside, etc.

In previous versions of Photos and iPhoto, I thought that you were able to edit what Photos considered a "Place." It gave you the option to expand the radius for a particular place, allowing you to group pictures together with that place name.

Is there a way to do this in the current version of Photos? It's very difficult to have to try to expand each stack to look for a photo. If I just type in "Home" it shows most of the photos, but since a few of them are down the street a bit, it misses them.

It seems to be a matter of GPS being off by 50' here and there, but it would be nice to be able to gather all of my "Home" photos on a location that I choose, like I was able to before.

Edit: Here's a screenshot of the view I'm referring to.
[image: Places view]

For example, all of those photos should be at 1 location, but they are kind of scattered around. I cannot select them all with Cmd-A, and Select All is greyed out.

Edit: According to [this older link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209116/how-do-i-change-geolocation-of-photos-in-the-photo-app) I might not be able to even do this in Photos. I can add a location if a photo doesn't have one, but can't change it if location already exists. I may need a separate tool to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can select all the photos that should be located at your home at once, and edit them together.

Open the info pane (command I) after selecting them. Type in a new location in the search box and every photo will get that new location.

If you want to find photos that are near your home, use the places view to pull up the photos you're looking for. By zooming out you'll see these photos grouped together. Then, select all of them (command A) and follow the above procedure.

Comment: Hi there! Thank you for the reply. I am unable to use "Select All" in the places view, as it's greyed out. I did make an edit to my original post with a bit more info too.

Comment: @TacoBob You have to zoom out a little bit until they coalesce - or do them one group at a time. Once you open a group, if you can't do command A, click the first and hold shift while clicking the last in the group.